# Copying timestamp format from avro to redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, avro

I am trying to copy an avro file to redshift using the COPY command. The file has a column that is of the type:

> {'name': 'timestamp',
>          'type': ['null', {'logicalType': 'timestamp-millis', 'type': 'long'}]}],
>
> Redshift variable type:   "timestamp" timestamptz

When I run the following command copy if fails:

```
COPY table_name 
from 'fil_path.avro' 
iam_role 'the_role' 
FORMAT AS avro 'auto'
```

> raw field value: 1581306474335
>
> Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSOF]

However If I add the following line It works:

```
timeformat 'epochmillisecs'
```

I tried to put my timestamp in microseconds which should be the base supported epoch resolution but it fails as well, and didn't find an appropriate name (epochmicrosecs didn't seem to do the job).
My question is why is it so?

Furthermore I have another field that is causing some problem. A date field which apparently is saved as a number of days in the avro file (7305) that gives the following error:

> Redshift variable type:   "birthdate" date
>
> avro: 'date_of_birth', 'type': ['null', {'type': 'int', 'logicalType': 'date'}]}
>
> Invalid Date Format - length must be 10 or more

Comment: I have no clue as of why my solution works. I had the same problem (date as number of days after epoch). I passed the date as text '2020-02-01' and it worked.

Comment: for avro logical type timestamp-millis (represents a date and time in milliseconds) the copy option TIMEFORMAT 'epochmillisecs' will work. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-timeformat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, about the Time Format:

As Docs states:

> COPY command attempts to implicitly convert the strings in the source data to the data type of the target column. If you need to specify a conversion that is different from the default behavior, `or if the default conversion results in errors`, you can manage data conversions by specifying the following [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-timeformat).

> First Solution:

Redshift Doesn't Recognize `epoch` time by default to be able to convert it to the format of `TimeStamp` as a result it can't extract year, month, day..etc from the `epoch` time to put them in the `TimeStamp Format`, as stated by the Docs:

> If your source data is represented as epoch time, that is the number of seconds or milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, specify 'epochsecs' or 'epochmillisecs'.

[This is the supported Formats that Redshift can convert Using automatic recognition.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/automatic-recognition.html)

- `TimeStamp` needs the format to be as `YYYYMMDD HHMISS = 19960108 040809` to be able to extract it right, that's what the error state `Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSOF]`, while `epoch` time format is just  `seconds or milliseconds since January 1, 1970` that it doesn't understand how to extract it's values from.
- `microseconds` isn't supported as a parameter for `TIMEFORMAT` in Redshift.

> Second Solution:

1. You won't need to pass `TIMEFORMAT` to the `COPY` command, but you will insert `epoch` time in your staging tables as `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`.
2. Then, when inserting `epoch` time from your staging tables into the schema tables convert it like this: `TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + epoch_time/1000 * interval '1 second' AS time`

> Secondly, about date field:

- `DATE` data type is specified as `Calendar date (year, month, day)` as stated by the [Docs,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html) As a result it can't be the number of days or be less than 10 characters in length (as 2021-03-04) and that's what the error tell us `Invalid Date Format - length must be 10 or more`.

> The solution for Date field:

1. You need to do a work-around, by passing the `number of days` as a `VARCHAR` or `text` to your staging tables.
2. When loading the schema tables from the staging tables, apply Data cleaning by convert `number of days` to a `DATE` using `TOCHAR`: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(number of days, '9999-99-99'),'YYYY-MM-DD')`

- As a result, `number of days` will be a valid `DATE` in your `schema tables`.